# How to display Django index page on app

Tags: python, django

I'm doing the Django tutorial, part 3: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/

I currently have this text in my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    output = ', '.join([p.question for p in latest_poll_list])
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

This works when i go to: 
`http://localhost:8000/polls/`, it displays the records

The problem is when I take the next step and change the views.py to:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from polls.models import Poll

def index(request):
    latest_poll_list = Poll.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_poll_list': latest_poll_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)
```

From `http://localhost:8000/polls/` it shows the following error:
TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/
From `http://localhost:8000/polls/index.html` it shows this error:
Page not found (404)

I have my mysite/urls.py set to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I have my poll/views.py set to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

I have my TEMPLATE_DIRS set to:

```
'/path/to/mysite/templates'
```

Why won't the page load with the new code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the entire `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting. But I suspect you have this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/mysite/templates'
)
```

when you should actually have this:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/path/to/mysite/templates',
)
```

Note the extra comma after the end of the string. The comma is required for a single-element tuple in Python - otherwise, it's just a string in brackets.

Comment: Daniel thanks I added on the comma but it still shows the same error... Anything else in the code that could be wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a file named `index.html` in templates/polls?

Comment: yes, index.html: the code is

'{% if latest_poll_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for poll in latest_poll_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ poll.id }}/">{{ poll.question }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
 </br>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}'

Comment: And is that `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting actually the *full* filesystem path to your templates directory? eg on a Mac it might be `'/Users/myname/django_projects/mysite/templates'`.

Comment: I changed the directory and now the http://localhost:8000/polls/ works!
However, the /polls/index.html still shows errors, as below:

Page not found (404)

Comment: Yes, because you don't have a URL set up for `/index.html` in polls/urls.py. Not sure why you'd want to, though, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named `polls` in templates directory and create an `index.html` file in it with the following content.

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
{% for p in latest_poll_list %}
<li>{{ p.question }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have the polls folder in the templates directory and have the index.html file already in it. 

The templates directory is in the mysite folder (mysite/templates/polls/index.html)

Comment: Then check the TEMPLATE_DIRS variable in settings.py as Daniel Roseman said.